# How to get the minimum (or maximum) boundary of a scatter plot in Matplotlib

Tags: python, dataframe, matplotlib

Say I have thousands of random `(x, y)` data points and I store `x`s and `y`s in two columns in a dataframe. It is important to note that all `x`s are integers, but `y`s are continuous numbers. If I plot them in a scatter plot using Matplotlib, it looks like below. Now I want to get the minimum boundary of the plot, which I depicted in a red curve. How should I do it? To make it clear, I want to get the indices for `(x,y)` pairs with the minimum `y` value for each `x`, so the length of the indices should be equal to `len(set(x))`.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is `df.grouby('x').min()` what you want?

A full example:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'x': np.random.randint(10, size=1000), 'y': np.random.rand(1000)})
df.plot.scatter('x', 'y', color='k')
df.groupby('x').min().plot(ax=plt.gca(), color='red')
```

To get the indices of the original dataframe you can use `idxmin` on the `groupby` e.g.

```
df.groupby('x').idxmin()
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The plot is nice, but what I really need is a list of the indexs.

Comment: `df.grouby('x').min()` will give you a data frame of the x and y minimums. Do you need the original indices?

Comment: Yes. Exactly. I want the indices of those minimum data points in the original dataframe, not the new dataframe

Comment: Ok, I've edited the answer. I think `idxmin` is what you are after

Comment: I think it should be ``df[1].groupby('x').idxmin()``, since I want the minimum of y value, but it's all good. Thanks for the answer. Really helps a lot.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,3,1,2,3],'B':[1.3,2.6,3.2,5.6,4.5,3.1]})
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(df.A, df.B, '-')
temp = df.groupby('A')['B'].min().reset_index()
ax.plot(temp.A, temp.B, 'r-')
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The plot is good, but what I really need is a list of the indexs.